# How much you have to pay taxes for selling gold in USA?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, savings

Imagine you don't trust the stock market nor the banks so you keep the money in your house.
Then you want to protect yourself from inflation and you buy gold.

Then one day you want to sell a considerable amounts of gold - say 2-10 kg.
You can try to sell to friends of course but if you want to sell it with papers to a company then how much you have to pay in tax for that?

I had to chose a country (USA) to be more specific in the title but answers about other countries are very welcome

Comment: @littleadv - The question is a duplicate indeed but it would be very nice to have data for other countries. Is there any solution for finding more?

Comment: You could post different questions for different countries. I note that the UK has a tax exemption for gold coins, for example: https://www.thegoldbullion.co.uk/tax-free-gold/

Comment: @pjc50 - I don't know, I'm a bit afraid some people might think I'm a spammer if I post 5 such questions for 5 different countries